# Magento 2.3 checkout show company name after radio select

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, shipping-address

We want to add a radio select option in our Magento 2.3 store, that hides the company name and fax field.

We would like to add a radio option to select: personal or company purchase.

If the option company purchase is select, it should display the field company name and fax.

We have this option in our Magento 1.9.4 store, but that's quite easy to add in the .phtml file.

Because Magento 2.3 uses the .html file for the shipping address, we can not add this option. We also would like to add this option for the billing address.

How can we achieve this? Is there any template file to overwrite?

Answer (score 3):

I came up with a start of a solution and from there you should see easily how you can complete your task. Please rate the answer if it helps you, if not do leave comments so that as a community we can learn.

I put my solution on a public repository.
https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/company-field

The main components in this repo are:
a frontend plugin:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="layout_checkout_process" type="Mbs\CompanyField\Plugin\CheckoutLayoutProcess" />
    </type>
</config>

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor;

class CheckoutLayoutProcess
{
    public function afterProcess(LayoutProcessor $subject, $jsLayout) {
        $customAttributeCode = 'purchase_type';
        $customField = [
            'component' => 'Mbs_CompanyField/js/form/element/purchaseType',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
                'id' => 'drop-down',
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.purchase_type',
            'label' => 'Purchase Type',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => ['required-entry' => true],
            'sortOrder' => 50,
            'id' => 'drop-down',
            'options' => [
                [
                    'value' => 'personal',
                    'label' => 'Personal',
                ],
                [
                    'value' => 'business',
                    'label' => 'Business',
                ]
            ]
        ];

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$customAttributeCode] = $customField;

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

and this will ensure the field is added to the checkout. In my repo, I did add the field only for shipping and you will need your implementation to replicate this snippet for billing.

and then below is the code for the js model that likely will be what helps you most:

```
    define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'uiRegistry'
], function (Select, registry) {
    'use strict';

    return Select.extend({
        defaults: {
            skipValidation: false
        },

        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.toggleCompanyField()
        },

        onUpdate: function () {
            this._super();

            this.toggleCompanyField()
        },

        toggleCompanyField: function () {
            registry.get('checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.company', function(field){
                if (field.visible()) {
                    field.hide()
                } else {
                    field.show()
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

also Magento builds a whole set of html around the select in the event you need to customise the select rendering.. see screenshot:[image]

Comment: Many thanks! Works perfect. I only have one questions left. How can we change it from a dropdown in to radio buttons?

Comment: great to see it helped, I'd asked a separate question to the community to know how to transform a select ui component into a radio. If you mention my name, I'd love to take a look but I am quite tight with time at this moment..

Comment: Thanks! I will create a new question for this. Do you have a easy and fast change to place the hidden company field in a own custom div. So that we can customize the div that is been hidden?

Comment: yes, you can add jquery as a dependency and then modify the DOM at will

Comment: Thanks! I am not quite getting it. Can you maybe edit your code, to add this div?

Comment: Change the element from select to radio is quite easy, just changed this: `                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/checkbox-set'`

Comment: thanks Henk for the update, well appreciated

Comment: Can you help me out with adding the div around? Can not get it right.

Comment: you are on my list but unfortunately, I tend to work on this site only once a week and only couple of hours.. If you need this sorted urgently, I advise to look into it in another way

Comment: No problem, we are developing a new M2 store, so we are not in a hurry. If you have some time to update this code, you will really help us out.

Comment: looks like we may have a winner, please look at this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264918/change-uiclass-component-rendering/264991#264991. It does seem this will be helping us.. tbc

Comment: Thanks! I just have check it, but I want to create a unique div around the input fields that are hidden. Not around the select element. So that we can easily edit the entire field of the fields that will be displayed or hidden.

Comment: I found out that your module does only work for the shipment address and not the billing address. How can we extend the code that it will also be applied for the billing address?

Comment: Hi Herve, Is there a change to help me out with this? :)

Comment: Hi, your question is very specific to you and your need. I have stopped answering questions that are one to one as it is not the purpose of the community.

Comment: Hi Herve, is there a other way to communicate about this? I really need a solution to solve this and I can not get the puzzle complete :)