# change uiclass component rendering

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I have a select in a Magento 2 template initialised using the uiClass with the code below:

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'jquery',
    'domReady',
], function (Select, $) {
    'use strict';

    return Select.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            $("#" + this.uid).closest('div').css('padding', '10px').css('border', '1px solid red')
        }
    })
});
```

Whilst the select appears as expected, I struggle to change its rendering with jquery.

Has anybody resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom template to your component using the `elementTmpl` parameter.

More information can be found here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-select.html