# how can I get the custom customer attributes dropdown box to checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer-attribute, dropdown-attribute

I created a customer custom attribute with options. It did show on the user profile(able to save and edit). How do I make this dropdown box also show at the checkout page? (above shipping method) It will show this selection box with (user predefined selection), so it will submit into the sales_order table and also update the change of this attributes to user profile?

Comment: please take a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263197/magento-2-3-checkout-show-company-name-after-radio-select/263207#263207 and thumb up if it helps, thanks